# QT QTcpServer in thread; how to close listening server on exit?

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qtcpserver

I have a thread subclass like this

```
class MyThread : public QThread
{
public:
    MyThread (void);
    ~MyThread (void);

    void run();

    void stop(); // close server and terminate thread

public slots:
    void slotCloseServer();

signals:
    void signalCloseServer();

private:
    QTcpServer* m_pServer;
};
```

and the `run()`  and the overall class definition is outlined below

```
MyThread::MyThread()
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(signalCloseServer()), this, SLOT(slotCloseServer()));
}

void MyThread::run()
{
    m_pServer = new QTcpServer();

    if(m_pServer->listen(QHostAddress(QHostAddress::LocalHost), 8888) == 0)
    {
        qCritical("Server listen failed.");
    }
    else
    {
        exec();
    }
}

void MyThread::stop()
{
    emit signalCloseServer();
    quit(); // terminate thread
}

void MyThread::slotCloseServer()
{
    if (m_pServer && m_pServer->isListening())
    {
        m_pServer->close();
    }
}
```

Now from the main thread, I want to call `stop()` so it would signal to the thread instance to close the server and terminate itself but it never gets to `slotCloseServer()` and the listening port does not get released.

Any thoughts as to how to release the server socket before the terminating the thread?

Thanks,

Comment: What about trying to use a signal to call stop, not direct function call?

Comment: @liuyanghejerry I have not tried that. instead calling `thread->stop()`, if I did `QTimer::singleShot(0, thread, SLOT(stop()))`, would that help ?

Comment: I think it should be. In multi thread Qt program, using signal and slot to call functions is a good way to prevent calling functions in different thread. Because if we use signal and slot, function calls will become a message from different thread, not a direct call.

Comment: Try connecting to QThread::finished () or QThread::terminated (), those should fire after the thread is died so your main thread to stop the server and destroy the object.

Answer (score 0):

Why not call slotCloseServer() from stop()?

```
void MyThread::stop()
{
    slotCloseServer(); // close server

    quit(); // terminate thread
}

void MyThread::slotCloseServer()
{
    if (m_pServer && m_pServer->isListening())
    {
        m_pServer->close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for the cases when something should be done when a created object is destroyed(in you case thread termination) better to state needed actions in destructor of class of that object:

```
MyThread ::~MyThread (void)
{
    m_pServer->close();
}
```